# Hibernate - groupby and sortby

Tags: java, group-by, hibernate-criteria

This is my code:

```
    DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ApplicantTO.class, "applicant");
    detachedCriteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("applicant.contact.contactId")));
    detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("applicant.backToBackMeeting.backToBackMeetingId", backToBackMeetingId));

    // create criteria
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ContactTO.class, "contact");
    criteria.createAlias("contact.representedCountry", "representedCountry", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contact.merged", false));
    criteria.add(Property.forName("contact.contactId").in(detachedCriteria));

    // set pagination and order
    criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize).setFirstResult(first);
    for (String sortField : sortProperties) {
        criteria.addOrder(Boolean.TRUE.equals(order) ? Order.asc(sortField) : Order.desc(sortField));
    }

    return criteria.list();
```

As you can see, ApplicantTO and ContactTO are 2 different entities: each Applicant is connected to a Contact, but not the other way around.

The sortProperties belong to the Contact, but I would like to add a new sortProperty related to the applicant.

My idea is to have something like this:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ApplicantTO.class, "applicant");
criteria.createAlias("applicant.contact", "contact", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("contact.representedCountry", "representedCountry", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("applicant.backToBackMeeting.backToBackMeetingId", backToBackMeetingId));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contact.merged", false));
for (ApplicantTO applicant : (List<ApplicantTO>) criteria.list()) {
    Hibernate.initialize(applicant.getContact());
}

// set pagination and order
criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize).setFirstResult(first);
for (String sortField : sortProperties) {
    criteria.addOrder(Boolean.TRUE.equals(order) ? Order.asc(sortField) : Order.desc(sortField));
}
criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("contact"));

return criteria.list();
```

But I receive the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column "dbo.C_CONTACT.LASTNAME" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1454)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:388)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:338)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:185)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:160)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:281)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    ... 154 more
```

Is there a way to sortby a property of an entity and then groupby a different entity?

Thanks

Comment: The cause of the error is obvious: you are using a column in `ORDER BY` which is not allowed (i.e. does not appear in `GROUP BY` or is an aggregate of a column).  The solution is to either add that sort by field to the select clause, or don't use it at all.

Comment: Try writing out your query in SQL Server and run it.  You will get the same error, and then you can debug it without the obfuscation of Java's criteria code, which is hideous IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand the error, I'm asking if there is any workaround or a differerent approach to what I'm trying to do.